# Linq Multiple Orderby Query in one Listing with multiple conditions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

```
var result = await projectRepo.GetPagedListAsync(x => new ProjectApiModel
            {
                ProjectId = x.Id,
                ProjectKey = x.ProjectKey,
                ProjectName = x.ProjectName,
                ProjectStatus = x.ProjectStatus,
                Tasks = x.Tasks.Where(z => /*z.AgentId == referenceId &&*/ z.Status == true && (z.TaskStatus == null || z.TaskStatus.StatusName != "Closed")).Select(y => new TaskApiModel
                {
                    TaskId = y.Id,
                    TaskName = y.TaskName,
                    ProjectId = y.ProjectId,
                    TaskTypeName = y.TaskType.TypeName,
                    TaskPriority = y.TaskPriorityId == null ? null : new PriorityModel { Name = y.TaskPriority.Name, Color = y.TaskPriority.Color, Id = y.TaskPriority.Id, Scale = y.TaskPriority.Scale },
                    TaskStatus = y.TaskStatusId == null ? null : new StatusModel { StatusName = y.TaskStatus.StatusName, Color = y.TaskStatus.Color, Scale = y.TaskStatus.Scale, StatusId = y.TaskStatus.Id, Status = y.TaskStatus.Status },
                    Deadline=y.EndDateUTC
                }).ToList()
            },orderBy: orders => orders.OrderBy(o => o.ProjectName));
```

This is what I am using for sorting my project list with the project name and its going well. Now I want to change the orderby by conditions as see below.

1. First want to show all the projects which contain TaskPriority as "urgent" 
   In any one of the tasks(Every project has tasklist).
2. rest all projects want to show an ascending order.
3. If any project name starting with numeric should be in last.

I tried the code

```
orderBy: orders => orders.OrderBy(o => o.Tasks.Any(s=>s.TaskPriority.Name.ToLower()== "urgent")).ThenBy(i=>i.ProjectName));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly. The reason why your query didn't work was when ordering booleans, False is ordered first.

What you need to do is Order By Descending in the first condition.

```
orders.OrderByDescending(o => o.Tasks.Any(s=>s.TaskPriority.Name.ToLower()== "urgent"))
       .ThenBy(i=>i.ProjectName));
```

For Example, mock your scenario with simpler version of your classes

```
public class Project
{
    public long ProjectId{get;set;}
    public string ProjectName{get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<ProjectTask> Task{get;set;}
}

public class ProjectTask
{
    public long TaskId{get;set;}
    public string TaskPriority{get;set;}
}
```

Client Code

```
var project1 = new Project
{
    ProjectId=1,
    ProjectName = "abc",
    Task = new []
    {
        new ProjectTask{TaskId=1,TaskPriority="urgent"},
        new ProjectTask{TaskId=1,TaskPriority="moderate"},
    }
};

var project2 = new Project
{
    ProjectId=2,
    ProjectName = "aaa",
    Task = new []
    {
        new ProjectTask{TaskId=1,TaskPriority="moderate"},
        new ProjectTask{TaskId=1,TaskPriority="moderate"},
    }
};


var project3 = new Project
{
    ProjectId=2,
    ProjectName = "abb",
    Task = Enumerable.Empty<ProjectTask>()
};

var project4 = new Project
{
    ProjectId=2,
    ProjectName = "abaa",
    Task = new []
    {
        new ProjectTask{TaskId=1,TaskPriority="moderate"},
        new ProjectTask{TaskId=1,TaskPriority="moderate"},
    }
};

var listOfProjects = new [] {project1,project2,project3,project4};

var r = listOfProjects.OrderByDescending(o => o.Task.Any(s=>s.TaskPriority.ToLower()== "urgent"))
                      .ThenBy(i=>i.ProjectName);
```

Sample Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your Detailed explanation.it's very helpful and I got the first two steps.But we missed the third one.If any project name starting with numeric should be in last.

Comment: Once again thank you for your valuable replay, I fixed the third one also.

`orderBy: orders => orders.OrderByDescending(o => o.Tasks.Any(s=>s.TaskPriority.Name.ToLower()== "urgent")).ThenBy(i=> Regex.IsMatch(i.ProjectName, @"^\d+")).ThenBy(y=>y.ProjectName));`